# Perform multiple unrelated operations on elements of a single stream in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I perform multiple unrelated operations on elements of a single stream?

Say I have a `List<String>` composed from a text. Each string in the list may or may not contain a certain word, which represents an action to perform. Let's say that:

- if the string contains 'of', all the words in that string must be counted
- if the string contains 'for', the portion after the first occurrence of 'for' must be returned, yielding a `List<String>` with all substrings

Of course, I could do something like this:

```
List<String> strs = ...;

List<Integer> wordsInStr = strs.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.contains("of"))
    .map(t -> t.split(" ").length)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> linePortionAfterFor = strs.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.contains("for"))
    .map(t -> t.substring(t.indexOf("for")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but then the list would be traversed twice, which could result in a performance penalty if `strs` contained lots of elements.

Is it possible to somehow execute those two operations without traversing twice over the list?

Comment: IMO, it's totally unnecessary to complicate your code for the non-existed performance issue. Iterating a list/collection in memory is pretty fast and fast even it's big. Again, IMO, if i'm the person who make decision in your code review, i will accept the code in the OP and reject the code in the accepted answer.

Comment: @123-xyz already hit the nail on the head. As a fun fact, you’re not caring about iterating twice when saying `contains("for")`, immediately followed by `indexOf("for")`, despite the fact that these operation *are* related and can be fused without sacrificing readability. And if you really care about performance, think about what `t.split(" ")` actually does when all you want, is to count the number of spaces. Iterating twice, when the operations are unrelated, is not a problem.

Comment: Maybe I should have formulated the problem more accurately. I attemped to put an example along with the post, and therefore I had to make up a simple use case. That use case doesn't make sense at all, and it's also badly implemented: indeed, applying `t.split(" ")` to only get the number of words actually *is* bad. But what if I don't have a list with elements, but a `Stream` obtained from a network connection or some I/O channel – that would change the use case significantly, isn't it?

Comment: @MCEmperor yes it might change things - depending on the size of the Stream collecting it into a Collection may still be worth the memory-cost if you need to use it for multiple unrelated operations, or it might be completely impossible (e.g. if the stream is infinite - of course all the unrelated operations would have to be short-circuiting in that case, which would probably be quite complicated either way).

Comment: @MCEmperor that will be a totally different question/scenario if the elements come from network/db calls. First of all, we should not duplicate the network/db calls even if the size is small or just one. Secondly, you still can save result of network/db call into a temp list and then do what you did in OP. Thirdly, if the size is too big to save or you don't want for some reasons, you can use `Pair/Triple` in the mapping function: `Function<? super T, Pair<R1, R2>> mapper = ...` before you start to think about creating some complex collector.

Comment: @123-xyz I don't think `Pair` will work, because the number of occurrences of `for` and `of` will be different in most cases, and putting the results together in a `Pair` a) will result in some `Pair`s having no left or right-hand value and b) doesn't reflect the semantics of a `Pair`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a single pass `Stream` then you have to use a custom `Collector` (parallelization possible).

```
class Splitter {
  public List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
  public List<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<>();

  public void accept(String s) {
    if(s.contains("of")) {
      counts.add(s.split(" ").length);
    } else if(s.contains("for")) {
      words.add(s.substring(s.indexOf("for")));
    }
  }

  public Splitter merge(Splitter other) {
    words.addAll(other.words);
    counts.addAll(other.counts);
    return this;
  }
}
Splitter collect = strs.stream().collect(
  Collector.of(Splitter::new, Splitter::accept, Splitter::merge)
);
System.out.println(collect.counts);
System.out.println(collect.words);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer to address the OP from a different aspect. First of all, let's take a look how fast/slow to iterate a list/collection. Here is the test result on my machine by the below performance test:

**When: length of string list = 100, Thread number = 1, loops = 1000, unit = milliseconds**

---

OP: 0.013

Accepted answer: 0.020

By the counter function: 0.010

---

**When: length of string list = 1000_000, Thread number = 1, loops = 100, unit = milliseconds**

---

OP: 99.387

Accepted answer: 89.848

By the counter function: 59.183

---

**Conclusion: The percentage of performance improvement is pretty small or even slower(if the length of string list is small). generally, it's a mistake to reduce the iteration of list/collection which is loaded in memory by the more complicate collector. you won't get much performance improvements. we should look into somewhere else if there is a performance issue.**

Here is my performance test code with tool [Profiler](https://github.com/landawn/AbacusUtil): (I'm not going to discuss how to do a performance test here. if you doubt the test result, you can do it again with any tool you believe in)

```
@Test
public void test_46539786() {
    final int strsLength = 1000_000;
    final int threadNum = 1;
    final int loops = 100;
    final int rounds = 3;

    final List<String> strs = IntStream.range(0, strsLength).mapToObj(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i + " of " + i : i + " for " + i).toList();

    Profiler.run(threadNum, loops, rounds, "OP", () -> {
        List<Integer> wordsInStr = strs.stream().filter(t -> t.contains("of")).map(t -> t.split(" ").length).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> linePortionAfterFor = strs.stream().filter(t -> t.contains("for")).map(t -> t.substring(t.indexOf("for")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        assertTrue(wordsInStr.size() == linePortionAfterFor.size());
    }).printResult();

    Profiler.run(threadNum, loops, rounds, "Accepted answer", () -> {
        Splitter collect = strs.stream().collect(Collector.of(Splitter::new, Splitter::accept, Splitter::merge));
        assertTrue(collect.counts.size() == collect.words.size());
    }).printResult();

    final Function<String, Integer> counter = s -> {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0, len = s.length(); i < len; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    };

    Profiler.run(threadNum, loops, rounds, "By the counter function", () -> {
        List<Integer> wordsInStr = strs.stream().filter(t -> t.contains("of")).map(counter).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> linePortionAfterFor = strs.stream().filter(t -> t.contains("for")).map(t -> t.substring(t.indexOf("for")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        assertTrue(wordsInStr.size() == linePortionAfterFor.size());
    }).printResult();
}
```

Comment: I suppose, replacing `.map(t -> t.split(" ").length)` with, e.g. `.map(t -> 1+(int)t.chars() .filter(c -> c==' ').count())`, has more impact for large data sets than saving an iteration, considering what happens behind the scenes in each case…

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom collector for that and iterate only once:

```
 private static <T, R> Collector<String, ?, Pair<List<String>, List<Long>>> multiple() {

    class Acc {

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Long> longs = new ArrayList<>();

        void add(String elem) {
            if (elem.contains("of")) {
                long howMany = Arrays.stream(elem.split(" ")).count();
                longs.add(howMany);
            }
            if (elem.contains("for")) {
                String result = elem.substring(elem.indexOf("for"));
                strings.add(result);
            }

        }

        Acc merge(Acc right) {
            longs.addAll(right.longs);
            strings.addAll(right.strings);
            return this;
        }

        public Pair<List<String>, List<Long>> finisher() {
            return Pair.of(strings, longs);
        }

    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::add, Acc::merge, Acc::finisher);
}
```

Usage would be:

```
Pair<List<String>, List<Long>> pair = Stream.of("t of r m", "t of r m", "nice for nice nice again")
            .collect(multiple());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 1 stream through a list, you need a way to manage 2 different states, you can do this by implementing Consumer to new class.

```
    class WordsInStr implements Consumer<String> {

      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

      @Override
      public void accept(String s) {
        Stream.of(s).filter(t -> t.contains("of")) //probably would be faster without stream here
            .map(t -> t.split(" ").length)
            .forEach(list::add);
      }
    }

    class LinePortionAfterFor implements Consumer<String> {

      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

      @Override
      public void accept(String s) {
        Stream.of(s) //probably would be faster without stream here
            .filter(t -> t.contains("for"))
            .map(t -> t.substring(t.indexOf("for")))
            .forEach(list::add);
      }
    }

    WordsInStr w = new WordsInStr();
    LinePortionAfterFor l = new LinePortionAfterFor();

    strs.stream()//stream not needed here
        .forEach(w.andThen(l));
    System.out.println(w.list);
    System.out.println(l.list);
```