# Is it possible to have split -> process -> collect data in a single Stream operation

Tags: java, java-stream

I don't want to split a stream into two but I want to add an operation that splits the data *before* I transform it.

To illustrate this, let's say I have some common object coming in:

```
public class CommonItem {
    private String name;
    private boolean isSelected;
   /* getters and setters */
}
```

I have these coming in to represent multiple different kinds of things like:

```
public class Foo {
    private String text;
    private boolean isChecked;

    public Foo(String text, boolean isChecked) {
        this.text = text;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }
   /* getters and setters */
}
```

and

```
public class Bar {
    private String title;
    private boolean isTicked;

    public Bar(String title, boolean isTicked) {
        this.title = title;
        this.isTicked = isTicked;
    }
   /* getters and setters */
}
```

So, in a Stream operation I can easily convert them to the item I want and and split them by the boolean property by doing

```
listOfCommonItems.stream()
    .map(item -> new Foo(item.getName(), item.isSelected()))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::isChecked));
```

This produces the output I want - a `Map<Boolean, List<Foo>>` split in two buckets - those which are checked and those which aren't. However, if I wanted the same kind of thing with `Bar` I have to do a different collection criteria

```
listOfCommonItems.stream()
    .map(item -> new Bar(item.getName(), item.isSelected()))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Bar::isTicked));
```

to get `Map<Boolean, List<Bar>>`.

I can use `.filter` but then I'd need to process the stream twice. It's similar if I split `CommonItem` into two and process those results afterwards.  And I don't exactly need two streams, as it's the same set of data, I just need it in two buckets where the common criteria comes before their transformation.

However, can I somehow do the splitting *before* the mapping, so I can easily have a single logic for the split based on `CommonItem` instead of one for the final converted item, then collect based on this criteria at the end?

Comment: What does `Converter::toFoo` actually do? Does it change the field values? If not, wouldn't the two code snippets produce the exact same result? I don't get why you say you can "split" them, because what you are doing is just mapping *all* the elements to Foo or Bar.

Comment: @Sweeper it maps `CommonItem` to `Foo` directly carrying the properties over to the other one. No change is involved. The objects are simple beans and carry no logic themselves - just some data as properties.

Comment: seems like a use-case more bound towards `Collectors.partitioningBy`, but really need a definition of what does the `Coverter`'s `toFoo` and `toBar` utils do.

Comment: OK, I guess I wasn't being clear - I'm splitting them by the boolean property, into two buckets, not by type. I just have multiple possible types that I can convert one item in, and I don't like having a separate split criteria for each.

Comment: Can you show some sample input and outputs? What data structure are you trying to get? An instancs of `HashMap<Boolean, Foo>` and an instance of `HashMap<Boolean, Bar>`?

Comment: Why not just use the `isSelected` field in `CommonItem`? Why are you trying to convert to Foo or Bar in the first place?

Comment: I would guess you eventually are interested in `Map<Boolean, List<Bar>>` and `Map<Boolean, List<Foo>>`, is that the case?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539786/perform-multiple-unrelated-operations-on-elements-of-a-single-stream-in-java

Comment: this might seem a bit overkill, but from what I understand, you want to have a single collector for both types of classes. One solution could be to have a common ancestor for `Foo` and `Bar` that has the `isTicked` property, and create the collector to work on the parent class

Comment: @Sweeper I don't want to use `CommonItem` because it's something coming from outside my application. And it can represent *different* things, let's say a user or a ToDo item. They come in the same base format from outside my application. And do not confuse the example with the real data, I've stripped down this to post here - in reality `Foo` and `Bar` will be a lot different in shape and use. The only similarity is that they have some fields that directly map to the base format of `CommonItem`

Comment: @nullpointer yes, I want the data transformed and bucketed by some criteria. But the common criteria is before the transformation.

Comment: @MCEmperor that's OK but it involves having a custom operation that does the conversion *and* splits on criteria. It would also be cumbersome to generalise to many different outputs. That's not really what I'm after. If that really is the only solution, then I suppose the answer to my question is "no".

Comment: @VLAZ I think the thing you want to achieve will become very hard. You want to split the common items into different classes, which have technically nothing in common (i.e. from the language's perspective, `Foo::isChecked` and `Bar::isTicked` are completely unrelated). That'll make things more complicated.

Comment: @MCEmperor I know, that's why I was wondering if I could "pre-split". Let's say do `commonItems.stream().tagForBucketing(item -> item.isSelected()).map(item -> new Foo()).collect(Collectors.groupByPreviouslyTagged())`. Obviously not with those names but that kind of operation - where you don't have to do the bucketing based on the final data type. It's honestly, while not *hard*, it's super annoying to have one grouping criteria per exit type when the input types are all the same. And I already do sorting based on `commonItem.getName()` then convert and collect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get you correctly, you want something like this:

```
public static <T> Map<Boolean,List<T>> splitData(
    List<CommonItem> listOfCommonItems, BiFunction<String,Boolean,T> mapper) {

    return listOfCommonItems.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(CommonItem::isSelected,
            Collectors.mapping(ci -> mapper.apply(ci.getName(), ci.isSelected()),
                Collectors.toList())));
}
```

to be usable as

```
Map<Boolean,List<Foo>> map1 = splitData(listOfCommonItems, Foo::new);
Map<Boolean,List<Bar>> map2 = splitData(listOfCommonItems, Bar::new);
```

You have to understand that `groupingBy(Function)` or `partitioningBy(Predicate)` are short-hands for `groupingBy(Function, toList())` resp. `partitioningBy(Predicate, toList())`. So you can write these forms explicitly when you want to insert additional operations like `mapping` the elements before adding them to the lists.

`partitioningBy` is a specialized form of `groupingBy` for boolean keys, which allows the underlying implementation to use optimized code for this case.

---

To do it in one Stream operation, you need a type capable of holding the result. With a class like

```
class Both {
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();
    void add(CommonItem ci) {
        String name = ci.getName();
        boolean sel = ci.isSelected();
        foos.add(new Foo(name, sel));
        bars.add(new Bar(name, sel));
    }
    Both merge(Both other) {
        if(foos.isEmpty()) return other;
        foos.addAll(other.foos);
        bars.addAll(other.bars);
        return this;
    }
}
```

you can collect all of them like

```
Map<Boolean, Both> map = listOfCommonItems.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(CommonItem::isSelected,
        Collector.of(Both::new, Both::add, Both::merge)));
```

though, for an ordinary `List`, there is no advantage in avoiding a traversal, so this would just be an unnecessary code complication.

Comment: OK, that seems to be what I want. Thanks, for some I didn't realise you could apply mapping as you collected the items into the final output. I'll wait before accepting the answer just in case.

Comment: I don't need to split into both `Foo` and `Bar` at the same time. I simply have something like `List<CommonItem> users` coming in which I want to turn into `List<Users>` and also separate based on the boolean. Then I might get `List<CommonItem> groups` that I want to do the same with. There are many other things that can be represented the same way, like countries or telephone numbers. These are not interchangeable inside the system, merely represented by the same shape of data when coming in.

Comment: Well, the addition was just for completeness. It might also help a bit understanding what’s going on in a collector. As already said, I think the first variant is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents.

```
List<CommonItem> listOfCommonItems = Arrays.asList(
    new CommonItem("foo", true),
    new CommonItem("bar", false),
    new CommonItem("bar", false),
    new CommonItem("foo", true),
    new CommonItem("foo", false),
    new CommonItem("bar", true),
    new CommonItem("bar", false)
);

Map<Class<?>, ? extends Map<Boolean, ? extends List<?>>> map = listOfCommonItems.stream()
    .map(item -> new SimpleEntry<>(item.isSelected(), convertCommonItem(item)))
    .collect(groupingBy(t -> t.getValue().getClass(), partitioningBy(
        Entry::getKey, mapping(t -> t.getValue(), toList()))));

    System.out.println(map);
```

Each class (`Foo`, `Bar`,...) is mapped to a `Partition` object, which is a `Map` containing the keys *true* and *false*. Each value of such partition now contains a list with the objects where the boolean property was the same.

The tag for bucketing, as you called it in the comments, is simply implemented by wrapping both the bucketing tag (the boolean) and the converted object into a sort of Pair (`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` in my case).

---

Here is some dummy implementation of the conversion. I do not exactly know how you was planning to convert the common items to their respective classes, but here is a simple implementation to provide a little context:

```
private static Object convertCommonItem(CommonItem commonItem) {
    switch (commonItem.getName()) {
        case "foo":
            return new Foo(commonItem.getName(), commonItem.isSelected());
        case "bar":
            return new Bar(commonItem.getName(), commonItem.isSelected());
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I really dislike how Java doesn't have a Pair or Tuple built in object. Well, other than `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` but using it outside maps or key-value pairs always feels like a hack. Unfortunately, I can't really decide whether to convert to `Foo` or `Bar` at conversion time - it's context-related operation. When I receive data for users, I want to convert to `User`. And when the data is for countries, then I don't want `User` as output. The input is a very generic DTO that carries no identifying information *itself* it's however part of a different DTO that you do a `getUsers` or similar.