# Java functional programming for multiple functionality with single stream data

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

There is a List of object like:-

```
ID     Employee    IN_COUNT    OUT_COUNT     Date
1        ABC          5           7        2020-06-11 
2        ABC          12          5        2020-06-12 
3        ABC          9           6        2020-06-13
```

This is the an employee data for three date which I get from a query in List object.
Not I want total number of `IN_COUNT` and `OUT_COUNT` between three date. This can be achieved by doing first iterating stream for only `IN_COUNT` and calling `sum()` and then in second iteration, only `OUT_COUNT` data can be summed. But I don't want to iterate the list two times.
How is this possible in functional programming using stream or any other option.

Comment: "But I don't want to iterate the list two times." Why not?

Comment: Why do you want to use streams or "functional programming", specifically? This would be trivial with a loop.

Comment: Can you give us some code, over working with it?

Comment: Without understanding exactly how your data is represented in java objects, there isnt much too say. But yes, when you do "pure streaming" and summing/collecting in the end, then you need "one stream per column". The only other way would be to use a stream like you use an ordinary for loop, where you proces each element for IN and OUT and sum up TWO "outside" counters.

Comment: You could also rewrite your query to return the sums directly - that would be more efficient unless you need the individual row data for something else.

Comment: Related: [Perform multiple unrelated operation on elements of a single stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539786/perform-multiple-unrelated-operations-on-elements-of-a-single-stream-in-java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called a 'fold' operation in functional programming. Java streams call this 'reduce' and 'sum', 'count', etc. are just specialized reduces/folds. You just have to provide a binary accumulation function. I'm assuming Java Bean style getters and setters and an all args constructor. We just ignore the other fields of the object in our accumulation:

```
List<MyObj> data = fetchData();
Date d = new Date();
MyObj res = data.stream()
    .reduce((a, b) -> {
        return new MyObj(0, a.getEmployee(),
            a.getInCount() + b.getInCount(), // Accumulate IN_COUNT
            a.getOutCount() + b.getOutCount(), // Accumulate OUT_COUNT
            d);
     })
    .orElseThrow();
```

This is simplified and assumes that you only have one employee in the list, but you can use standard stream operations to partition and group your stream (groupBy).

If you don't want to or can't create a MyObj, you can use a different type as accumulator. I'll use `Map.entry`, because Java lacks a Pair/Tuple type:

```
Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> res = l.stream().reduce(
        Map.entry(0, 0), // Identity
        (sum, x) -> Map.entry(sum.getKey() + x.getInCount(), sum.getValue() + x.getOutCount()), // accumulate
        (s1, s2) -> Map.entry(s1.getKey() + s2.getKey(), s1.getValue() + s2.getValue()) // combine
    );
```

What's happening here? We now have a reduce function of `Pair accum, MyObj next -> Pair`. The 'identity' is our start value, the accumulator function adds the next MyObj to the current result and the last function is only used to combine intermediate results (e.g., if done in parallel).

Too complicated? We can split the steps of extracting interesting properties and accumulating them:

```
Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> res = l.stream()
    .map(x -> Map.entry(x.getInCount(), x.getOutCount()))
    .reduce((x, y) -> Map.entry(x.getKey() + y.getKey(), x.getValue() + y.getValue()))
    .orElseGet(() -> Map.entry(0, 0));
```

Comment: You don't need to return a `new MyObj` every time. You can simple `sum` those values in `a` or `b` and return it.

Comment: @KunLun in this case, the return value has to be 'MyObj', so I need to return a MyObj. The signature of reduce is: (T, T) -> T

Comment: If the list is to big, you will create to much instances and this can be harmful. Look at my answer to understand. I create an identity object and sum everything there.

Comment: True, this may produce a lot of garbage. One could also modify and return the first argument. Unfortunately, with immutable classes like in my Map.entry example, you have no choice but create new instances. The garbage collector should be able to handle that though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to done this:

```
public class Counts{

    private int inCount;
    private int outCount;

    //constructor, getters, setters

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    List<Counts> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Counts(5, 7));
    list.add(new Counts(12, 5));
    list.add(new Counts(9, 6));

    Counts total = list.stream().reduce(

                       //it's start point, like sum = 0
                       //you need this if you don't want to modify objects from list
                       new Counts(0,0), 

                       (sum, e) -> {

                           sum.setInCount( sum.getInCount() + e.getInCount() );
                           sum.setOutCount( sum.getOutCount() + e.getOutCount() );

                           return sum;

                       }

                   );

    System.out.println(total.getInCount() + " - " + total.getOutCount());

}
```